# Creating Classroom using App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-classroom

I'm trying to create Google classrooms from a spreadsheet using App Script. I can create the classes successfully, but it's not adding the course materials (1 Doc) to the about page.

This is the code I am using and I've tried using the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/create) to no avail.

Can someone please advise me on how to correctly format the courseMaterialSets to include a Google Doc from my drive.

```
var create = Classroom.Courses.create({
"ownerId": '-My email address-',
  "name": getData[i][0],
  "section": getData[i][1],
  "descriptionHeading": getData[i][2],
  "description": getData[i][2],
    "courseMaterialSets" : [{
            "title" : 'Course Outline',
            "materials" : [{
                    "driveFile" : { 
                            "id" : getData[i][5],
                            "title" : 'Course Outline' ,
                            "alternateLink": getData[i][4], 
                            "thumbnailUrl" : 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=-Image ID-',

                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
}
Logger.log(create)
}
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I've updated the code to reflect the suggestions in the comments and logged the value of `var create` which returns all of the info of the newly created Classroom but with no mention of the course material set.

Comment: Classroom.Courses.create({
    "ownerId" : '------@-----------',
    "name" : getData[i][0],
    "section" : getData[i][1],
    "descriptionHeading" : getData[i][2],
    "description" : getData[i][2],
    "courseMaterialSets" : [{
   "title": string,
            "materials" : [{
                    "driveFile" : {
                        {
        "id": string,
        "title": string,
        "alternateLink": string,
        "thumbnailUrl": string,
      }
                    },
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
});
}
}

Comment: It's what I'm understand from the [Classroom documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#Course). Sorry for double comment, not enough space.

Comment: Have you tested the above code? I have tried again using the format with no success. Creates the class ok but no class materials.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#CourseMaterial) you have to [specify the `DriveFile` object](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/DriveFile) with JSON.

```
"driveFile" : {
   "id":            theDocIdString,
   "title":         theDocTitleString,
   "alternateLink": urlToFileString,
   "thumbnailUrl":  imgThumbnailString 
   }
```

You can of course pull all of this data from a sheet or use variables to loop through resources.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have tried again using the format with no success. Creates the class ok but no class materials.

Comment: Are you catching and logging any errors when you run the program? Without more information, it's hard to pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: Please see my edit. I'm not getting any errors when I run the program. It completes and creates the classroom successfully but doesn't add the course materials to the about page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I tried to successfully create a course, but I also do **not** get the course materials to attach to the ABOUT tab of the Google Classroom created.

```
function createCourse() {
  var resource = {
    name: "XYZ course",
    room: "The Great Hall",
    ownerId: "me",
    courseMaterialSets: [{
      title: "course materials",
      materials: [
      {

        driveFile: {
          id: "insert id of google drive file" 

        }


      }
      ],
  }],
  }
  var newCourse = Classroom.Courses.create(resource);


}
```

I also tried creating the course and then accepting the course in Google Classroom and the trying to add the classroom set. This also was not successful.

```
function addClassSet() {
  var id = "course id obtained with sample script in documentation";
  var resource = {
    name: "XYZ course",
    room: "The Great Hall",
    courseMaterialSets: [{
      title: "course materials",
      materials: [
      {

        driveFile: {
          id: "drive file id" //drive file was not added

        }


      }
      ],
  }],
    description: "This is a trial course", //this worked
  }
  Classroom.Courses.update(resource, id);
}
```

Is it because the [documentation states](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#CourseMaterialSet) that the courseMaterialsSets is Read only???

Comment: What Brian said above is correct, I believe. Supplying just the id parament is not enough, you must supply all of the parameters in the JSON object (I haven't tested it). That part of the documentation relates to  a resource object i.e. retrieving information from an existing class which is why it says 'read-only'.