# Google script to add material to the "ABOUT" section in Google Classroom

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I am trying to add material to the "ABOUT" section in Google Classroom by a Google Apps Script. This should be easy, but it is not working. It is giving me the following error: "course: No course was specified". I know 100% that the courseId is the one given in the script below, given that I have added assignments to it already.

```
function addMaterial () {
 var ID = Classroom.Courses.get("10404033071");
 var nm = {
    title: "test",
    materials: [{link:{url: "URL"},}],
    }
 var CC = Classroom.newCourseMaterialSet(nm);
 Classroom.Courses.update(CC, ID);
}
```

If I try the following way, no error message is given, but nothing is added to the "ABOUT" section.

```
function addMaterial () {
 var course = Classroom.Courses.get("10404033071");
  course.courseMaterialSets = [{ 
    title: "test",
    materials: [{
    link:{
      url: "URL",
        },}],
  }],
 Classroom.Courses.update(course, "10404033071");
}
```

Comment: Where's that part in the code that says About section should be updated?

Comment: The Classroom API documentation mentions it for the method courseMaterialSets[]: "Sets of materials that appear on the "about" page of this course."
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses

Comment: 'This should be easy' I thought the same - see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888104/creating-classroom-using-app-script) about the same topic. I only needed to create 10 classrooms so I didn't spend too long figuring it out, but form the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/Link) you must create a link object and use that in the material object.

Comment: I created a Google Form for teachers that would allow them to force add students to Classroom by supplying the invitation code and selecting the students in the form then using the Classroom and Admin APIs. I figured out the objects through this project but never got back to the Classroom materials as there was little demand for it.

Comment: @JamesDonnellan : I didn't see a given resolution to your question anywhere with the link you offered.  You say "I didn't spend too long figuring it out" here, but it mentions there "I've updated the code to reflect the suggestions in the comments and logged the value of var create which returns all of the info of the newly created Classroom but with no mention of the course material set." If you got it to work, then how? Thanks.

Comment: Then this could be a bug. If no one answers this specifically within a week, then I will see this with Google, because I have everything else working with the API (creating/deleting courses, adding/removing students and teachers, programming assignments, etc.), but this still does not work and there is nothing anywhere that indicates that it shouldn't.

Comment: @JasonJurotich, I'm very sorry, I should have said 'I didn't spend too long trying to figure it out', I was trying to say I didn't get it to work and as you can see the responses to that question I posted didn't actually provide any solution either. In my second post, I figured out the importance of how the objects are constructed so I just assumed that I wasn't constructing the materials objects correctly. I learned far more from reading code on GitHub than I did from Google's documentation!! But as you say it could very well be a bug that has never been flagged/ fixed due to low demand.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, As far as I can tell `courseMaterialSets` appears to be a Read-only property in the Google Classroom API v1.

[API LINK, See the description, of `courseMaterialSets` in the 
"Fields" Area](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses)